# PhaseInterceptorChain interceptor for {XXX}/ Service has thrown exception, unwinding now

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, cxf

I have a SOAP Service which I am deploying on JBoss EAP 6.1 server. I can see the Service is properly registered and when I hit the endpoint URL with ?WSDL I can see the WSDL too. But when I hit the endpoint, I am getting HTTP 500 error and on the Console, I can see the below error message.

> 12:41:26,921 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started (with errors) in 15986ms - Started 633 of 699 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 61 services are passive or on-demand)
>   12:41:39,044 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Interceptor for {http://webservice.xyz.abc.com/}MyService has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.SimpleMethodDispatcher.getMethod(SimpleMethodDispatcher.java:97) [cxf-rt-core.jar:2.6.4]
>       at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:129) [jbossws-cxf-server.jar:4.1.1.Final]
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57) [cxf-api.jar:2.6.4]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
>       at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) [cxf-api.jar:2.6.4]
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106) [cxf-api.jar:2.6.4]
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) [cxf-api.jar:2.6.4]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-api.jar:2.6.4]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239) [cxf-rt-transports-http.jar:2.6.4]
>       at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:92) [jbossws-cxf-server.jar:4.1.1.Final]
>       at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:143) [jbossws-cxf-server.jar:4.1.1.Final]
>       at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87) [jbossws-cxf-server.jar:4.1.1.Final]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286) [cxf-rt-transports-http.jar:2.6.4]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:211) [cxf-rt-transports-http.jar:2.6.4]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135) [jbossws-cxf-server.jar:4.1.1.Final]
>       at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-3900) bug report this happens when the URL you are invoking is wrong. Please make sure that you are passing in the correct URL.